# Alexa Skill doesn't respond after Ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

## This code works perfectly

```
var app = new Alexa.app('appName');
// ...
app.intent('marcopolo', {
  'slots': {},
  'utterances': ['marco']
}, function(request, response){
  console.log('marco worked');
  response.say('polo').shouldEndSession(false).send();
});

// Alexa says: polo
// Log says: marco worked
```

## This code does not work

```
var app = new Alexa.app('appName');
// ...
app.intent('marcopolo', {
  'slots': {},
  'utterances': ['marco']
}, function(request, response){
  console.log('marco started');
  return ajax('http://www.google.com')
    .then(function(){
      console.log('marco response');
      response.say('polo').shouldEndSession(false).send();
    })
    .catch(function(){
      console.log('marco error');
      response.say('polo, I think').shouldEndSession(false).send();
    });
});

// alexa says: (no response)
// Log says: marco started
```

I have tried using both [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) and [superagent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent) as the Ajax library with the same result.

Here are the versions:

```
"alexa-app": "^2.4.0",
"request-promise": "^2.0.0",
"superagent": "^3.8.3"
```

Here is my Alexa skill intent:

```
"intents": [
  {
    "name": "marcopolo",
    "slots": [],
    "samples": [ "marco" ]
  }
]
```

I have never seen an example of `app.intent()` taking a `return` statement, but I read a response somewhere online that suggested that returning a promise was required for async inside `app.intent()`, but this update had no effect:

```
return ajax('http://www.google.com')
```

I also thought maybe it was slow and timing out, but my Alexa Skill Timeout is set to 5 minutes. I have other skills that do Ajax without a problem, and the code all runs on Lambda (a cloud service), so I can't imagine anything environmental would cause the issue.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I've found [this documentation of Async Handlers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/alexa-app#asynchronous-handlers-example) but seem to be doing exactly the same thing. I must not be handling the promise correctly...

Answer (score 1):

## This code works

```
var ajax = require('request-promise');
//...
app.intent('marcopolo', {
  'slots': {},
  'utterances': ['marco']
}, function(req, res){

  ajax('http://google.com').then(function() {
    console.log('success');
    res.say('polo').send();
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err.statusCode);
    res.say('not working').send();
  });
  return false;

});
```

As it turns out, a `return` statement is required, and it has to be `false`. I wasn't able to find any place this is documented, nor any explanation about what a `return false` means to `app.intent()`. Returning `undefined` or the Promise object breaks the interaction.